# starmap_async bypasses the print function

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, iterator, multiprocessing

So here is the code I am running:

```
from itertools import product
from functools import partial

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing as mp

def func1(n0_tup, n1_tup, n3, df):
    df = df.copy()
    df = df.astype(object)

    X = pd.DataFrame({'col0': np.repeat(-n0_tup[1],n1_tup[0]),
                      'col1': n3*np.arange(n1_tup[0]),
                       'col2': n3*np.repeat(n1_tup[1],n1_tup[0]),
                       'col3': [f'random string {i}' for i in range(n1_tup[0])]})

    X['col4'] = func2(n1_tup[0], X.shape[0])
    temp = (n0_tup[1],n1_tup[0],n1_tup[1],n3)
    ind = (n0_tup[0],n1_tup[0],n1_tup[1])

    df[f'special col {temp}'] = n0_tup[1]+n1_tup[0]+n1_tup[1]+n3

    df2 = df
    df2[f'special col2 {temp}'] = n0_tup[1]+n1_tup[0]+n1_tup[1]+n3

    df3 =df2
    df3[f'special col3 {temp}'] = n0_tup[1]+n1_tup[0]+n1_tup[1]+n3

    print(temp)#<----This line gets skipped over by starmap_async

    return ind, temp, X['col2'].sum()+ df3[f'special col3 {temp}'].sum()

def main3():
    xd = pd.DataFrame({'col1': list('just a string')})
    A_lst = np.arange(1,10+1)
    A_size = A_lst[-1]+1
    B_rge = np.arange(660,670)
    B_size = len(B_rge)

    lst1 = (item for item in product(A_lst, repeat = 2) if item[0] < item[1])
    lst2 = enumerate(np.arange(660,670))
    arg_list = product(lst2, lst1)

    with mp.Pool(processes = mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
        result = pool.starmap_async(partial(func1, n3 = 100, df = xd), arg_list).get()

    result_fin = np.zeros([B_size, A_size - 1, A_size])
    for item in result:
        ind = item[0]
        result_fin[ind[0], ind[1], ind[2]] =item[2]

    return result, result_fin

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result_main3 = main3()
```

I just started learning multiprocessing and created a function to be multiprocess'd as a learning material. As I delved into the async stuff and I stumbled across this problem. The print function gets skipped over! I am simply using the print function to make sure things are running asynchronously, but with print function being skipped over, this seems impossible. My questions are the following:

1) Why does print function get skipped over and how can I enable it?

2) Is there a simple way to monitor whether the codes are being run asynchronously other than the print function?

3) Assume changing the func1 is not allowed, is it possible to speed up the code even further? If so, how?

Thank you guys in advance

EDIT: removed some unused imports

Comment: this works for me  (Python 3.7.3, numpy 1.16.3, Pandas 0.24.2, Linux 5.0.13), by working I mean I get output from `print`.  BTW `func2` isn't defined, so I just set that column to 42...

Comment: note that your `df2 = df` probably isn't doing what you expect, it would probably be worth watching: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns .  also every value passed though the `Pool` is implicitly copied (everything is serialised via `pickle` and back) so probably no need to do that explicitly, also a `Pool` by default uses `cpu_count` for the number of processes.  and `pool.starmap_async(...).get()` is the same as `pool.starmap(...)`

Comment: Thanks for the input. The reason why print is bypassed is probably because I am using Python 3.6.8 instead of 3.7.3. I do have a question though; why is pool.startmap_asyc(...) the same as pool.starmap(...)? I mean one is async and another is sync. and shouldn't async multiprocessing be run slightly faster than sync counterpart?

Comment: Also, thanks for pointing out df2 = df. Should have used df2 = df.copy() as a good practice

Comment: everything run through the pool is executed in a parallel/async set of processes.  this is just about when you want/need the results back.  saying that you want the results at some point in the future (`starmap_async`) then immediately waiting for them (`.get()`) is the same as saying you need the results immediately (`starmap`).  the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L270) says they're identical, so you're just unnecessarily complicating your code

Comment: also using `.copy()` isn't "good practice", it's fundamentally different semantics. there's no purpose just doing `df2 = df` in your posted code, just refer to `df`

Comment: the reason I include df2 = df and these df3 = df2 nonsense inside func1 in the first place is to make the func1 itself 'heavier', as to mimic the workload of the actual function I eventually want to run multiprocessing with.

Comment: those are going to take much less than a microsecond to execute, probably tens of nanoseconds, it's just copying a reference/pointer (and updating their reference count)...